# My RPGLE program is unable to to read SOAP exception response completely. I used WSDL2RPG.sh to generate the C and RPG stubs

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

My RPGLE program is unable to read the SOAP Exception response completely. Program is reading it partially.

Below snap shots of program and response received and recorded -

```
If pThis_t.excOccurred  = *On;                                                
   // Error Code -->  pThis_t.excCode  Error Indicator --> pThis_t.excOccurred
   O@ErrDes  = %Trim(pThis_t.excString);                                      
   RGAERI = C#Y;                                                              
   RGAERC = pThis_t.excCode;                                                  
   RGAERD = %Trim(pThis_t.excString);                                         
   //O@ErrFlg = C#Y;                                                          
   O@ErrDes  = %Trim(RGAERD);                                                 
Endif;
```

SOAP Exception Response XML -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>request message schema validation error</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <ns2:SOAPServiceException xmlns:ns2="http://www.sampleservice.com/schema/services/xyz/v1">
               <errorCode>100</errorCode>
               <errorMessage>javax.xml.bind.MarshalException - with linked exception: [org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-pattern-valid: Value '(905)40&amp;-2468       ' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '[0-9,\-,(,),X,x,.,+,\s+]+' for type 'PhoneType'.]</errorMessage>
            </ns2:SOAPServiceException>
         </detail>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Response XML read by RPGLE program -

```
 "AxisSoapException: SOAP fault occurred:  faultcode  : soap:Server faultstring: request message schema validation error faultactor :"
```

How can I read the complete SOAP Exception?

Regards

Comment: The requesting message was bad.  Hence the call to the webservice was bad.  That's what I get from it anyways.  The phone number wasn't formatted as expected by the web service.

Comment: Thanks Danny for response. I put the wrong value intentionally for testing purpose. Issue is with SOAP fault (Error Handling), I am getting correct SOAP exception while my RPGLE program and C/RPG stubs are not picking the SOAP response completely. If you can help me on the issue.

Comment: That's as far as I can go with a rpgle webservice.  I can help with RPG calling a java program that calls a webservice in another question.

Comment: Need to see the code for the procedures you're using...what are you using to parse the SOAP message?